# Custom links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

Rails has a few built in helper methods for dealing with links (url_for, link_to, auto_link), but none do exactly what I need:

I want the user to be able to specify a URL, and for me to be able to alter the text it appears as. auto_link almost does what I want, except you can't change the link text, and it doesn't recognize links that are typed in like: stackoverflow.com. You have to enter www.stackoverflow.com

I want the user to be able to enter something like "stackoverflow.com", and for me to be able to generate html like this:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Username</a>
```

Is there a plugin out there that adds additional link helper methods?

Comment: To override the regex of `auto_link`, you can create a ruby file in `config/initializers/auto_link_regex.rb` and paste code as given https://gist.github.com/715149. Modify the regex the way you want. I am unable to crack the regex that would work for your problem though. Still trying.

Comment: you can check that regexp in rubular.com, i've tried Chirantan's version on a few test cases and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a block to auto_link, and the result of that will be the link text. For example:

```
<% str = "something like http://stackoverflow.com would be the input" %>
<%= auto_link(str) do |url|
      "Username"
    end
%>
```

generates this HTML:

```
something like <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Username</a> would be the input
```

And if you wanted the link text to be different depending on what the URL was, you could do something like:

```
<% str = "something like http://stackoverflow.com, and another http://stackexchange.com url" %>
<%= auto_link(str) do |url| 
  if url.match(/overflow/) 
    "Username"
  else
    "Something"
  end
end %>
```

which generates:

```
something like <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Username</a>, and another <a href="http://stackexchange.com">Something</a> url
```

This plus the tips in the comments about adjusting the URL regex seem like they would do what you want.